# DynamicParameters fails to add template if ForEach is chained after ToList

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a function that dynamically builds sql statements based on an existing model and then adds some common fields that exist in every table.

The problem is that I'm experiencing some odd behaviour when I try to add the common fields.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Dapper;

public class Program
{
    private static readonly dynamic[] Data = new dynamic[] { new {Foo = 1, Bar = 2}, new {Foo = 3, Bar = 4} }; 
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }

    public static void Broken()
    {
        var parameters = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)Data).Select(x => new DynamicParameters(x));
        parameters.ToList().ForEach(x => x.AddDynamicParams(new {Bax = 7}));
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(""))
        {
            // This fails with a "Must declare scalar variable @Bax".
            connection.Execute("INSERT INTO DataTable(Foo, Bar, Bax) VALUES(@Foo, @Bar, @Bax)", parameters);
        }
    }

    public static void Working()
    {
        var parameters = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)Data).Select(x => new DynamicParameters(x)).ToList();
        parameters.ForEach(x => x.AddDynamicParams(new {Bax = 7}));
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(""))
        {
            // This works fine.
            connection.Execute("INSERT INTO DataTable(Foo, Bar, Bax) VALUES(@Foo, @Bar, @Bax)", parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

If you'll notice, the only difference is the position of my call to `.ToList()`. In the `Broken` function, I call it as part of a chain before `.ForEach` and in the the `Working` function, I call it on the same line as the assignment.

I've tried replacing the call to `AddDynamicParams` with individual `Add` calls for each parameter, but it doesn't seem to matter. I've also tried doing `for(var parameter in parameters) { parameter.AddDynamicParams(new {Bax = 7}) }` with no luck.

Unfortunately, there's no good way that aware of to show the `templates` without setting a breakpoint and examining the `.templates` attribute of the object in Visual Studio. If someone can provide a better way to demonstrate the template disappearing, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `Broken` method you are effectively enumerating your collection twice. This is due to [LINQ Deferred Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example).

This line:

```
 parameters.ToList().ForEach(x => x.AddDynamicParams(new {Bax = 7}));
```

Will enumerate your `IEnumerable<dynamic>` by creating a `List<dynamic>`, which you are modifying using `ForEach`, but then you do not use this list at all, and again pass your `parameters` object to the `connection.Execute` method:

```
connection.Execute("**your query**", parameters);
```

Whenever Dapper enumerates the `parameter` object it will again *project* each object (which are **not** the same objects found inside the above list) and thus creating a new instance which is not modified using `AddDynamicParams`.

To be more clear, your broken method is equivalent to the following:

```
public static void Broken()
{
    var parameters = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)Data).Select(x => new DynamicParameters(x));
    var parametersList = parameters.ToList(); // you create a list
    parametersList.ForEach(x => x.AddDynamicParams(new {Bax = 7})); // then you modify that list

    // parametersList != parameters

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(""))
    {
        // This fails with a "Must declare scalar variable @Bax".
        connection.Execute("INSERT INTO DataTable(Foo, Bar, Bax) VALUES(@Foo, @Bar, @Bax)", parameters); // but here you are passing the old parameters collection
    }
}
```

To solve your issue either use your `Working` version, or use again LINQ to create a working enumerable version:

```
var parameters = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)Data).Select(x =>
{
    var p = new DynamicParameters(x);
    p.AddDynamicParams(new {Bax = 7});
    return p;
});
```

Comment: I see. I would not have expected deferred execution to be an issue here, as I assumed that the `ToList` would force evaluation of each object and that the iterator would use that evaluated version from there out.

Comment: `ToList` returns a new object, it does nothing on the source of the enumeration.